# No mouse and close/maximize button Elementary OS

Tags: desktop, bugs, elementary-os

I've downloaded and installed Elementary OS in my laptop, but something weird is happening with me.

I made an USB Flash Drive installation, using UNetbootin. I was able to test it (like a Live-CD) and everything went just fine. So I decided to install it.

When I installed it, these bugs started to happen:

- The mouse pointer takes ~30 seconds to appear (i'm still able to click things), and when it does, all I see is an "X" on my screen. Perhaps this is the standard mouse pointer, right?
- When I try to close or maximize a window, the top bar with these options just doesn't exists. I'm able to drag the window across the screen, but when I double-click (hoping the window will maximize), the system stops working for a while, and then the window crashes.
- I've tested Elementary OS before installing. When I click something in the Plank, a small animation starts playing. This doesn't happen in the installed version.

There are other things happening, but these are the "main bugs" I can remember now.

I tried to do these:

- I tried reinstalling the system. Still the same.
- I tried to update the system. 100mb of updates, and the bugs didn't go away.
- A friend of mine asked me to type "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo-apt get upgrade" in the terminal. Still the same.

Since I've always been a Windows user, I don't know why this is happening and neither I know how can I fix this.

My laptop config is: 
Dell Inspiron 14R (5420), Core i7 3612QM 2.10GHz, 8GB RAM, nVidia 630GT 1GB and 1TB storage.

Any thoughts?

Comment: all this should not happen. have you by any chance tested another ubuntu-based distro on the same computer?

Comment: I tried to use Ubuntu 13.04, it somehow worked.

Comment: Same problem on VirtualBox...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to **deactivate the nVidia drivers**.
You can do this by going into the 'Software Center' and search for 'nVidia'.
If you are not able to click on the search bar, wait and try **ctrl+F**

Some drivers are hidden, so make sure you press the link in the lower-left corner.
It should say 'show 83 technical items'.
You will be able to find 'jockey common' (or User interface and desktop integration ...) which I assumed would cause the problem. I deactivated all nVidia related drivers and utilities as I will not use them anyway.

Someone else posted the following solution in another thread:

> What I’ve done, was disabling the NVIDIA Card in the BIOS, by changing
>   a specific setting in the BIOS from “Switchable graphics” →
>   “Integrated graphics”.

[Source on ElementaryOS.org](http://elementaryos.org/answers/my-windows-and-cursor-is-all-messed-up-1)

Answer (score 0):

**Try to update the linux kernel and install the recommended Nvidia driver:**

open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+Del) and type :

```
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get install linux-generic;
```

Then  install the recommended Nvidia driver :

open terminal and type:

```
jockey-gtk
```

wait for moments then select the option with [Recommended] and click  Activate

when the driver download and installation complete, reboot the system .